# How to check if a VSTO Outlook Explorer object has been closed

Tags: c#, vsto, outlook-addin

Some times when my Outlook VSTO Addin is running I get the following exception:

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0xD0720009): The Explorer
>   has been closed and cannot be used for further operations. Review your
>   code and restart Outlook.

I don't know why the Explorer object has been closed because I haven't called the Marshall.ReleaseCOMObject method on it. I've already spent way too long looking into it with no success, and  it isn't causing the users any problems. So I'm just ignoring it (which isn't the best I know, but I needed to draw a line in the sand somewhere).

But it would be nice to be able to check whether the Explorer object has been closed before trying to use one of its properties / method and an exception being thrown.

Is this possible?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

If the user closed the Explorer, it is gone and you will get that error. You need to trap the Explorer.Close event.

Comment: That's the problem. The Close event isn't getting raised, as I've already got code in a Explorer Close event handler proc to dispose of the Explorer object reference. I couldn't seem to get to the bottom of it. So my code thinks the Explorer object is still valid, and goes bang when it tries to use the Explorer object that is deemed to be closed. I've got a try catch a round it, but I'd rather check the object, than rely on an exception being thrown to indicate the Explorer object is actually closed.